# How to hide the vertical glowing bar in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, code-editor

Please help me to hide this vertical glowing bar in PhpStorm.

[image]

Comment: Your question shows [no attempt](//idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you have made an attempt, you should edit our question to detail exactly what you did, researched for, and point to any links that were helpful but that did not answer your question. Your attempts should be turned into a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clear to read and understand. Also read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting is named "Enable HTML/XML tag tree highlighting", found under Editor->General->Appearance.

I would leave it on,  as it helps to support the readability of large documents.

Comment: thanks Philipp for help. i know its helps us in big project, i just wanted to know how its hide... i thing u understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, I dont use phpstorm but try it under Settings - Editor - Appearance and then deselect Show right margin.

Comment: in my default webstorm and intellij there is no such line, i think its from a plugin you installed, can you maybe name that to me or try to edit that plugins setting. by the way ur editor looks really nice :)

Comment: no, it's only show in laravel blade file.... b8 not showing in html file... i thing this is not for plugins